# Get the latest record from the join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT f.name, MAX( cmt.created_at ) AS CommentDate, cmt.comment AS LastComment
FROM families f
LEFT JOIN comments cmt ON f.id = cmt.commentable_id
WHERE f.id =12212
```

I get the last date of the comment, but instead of getting the last comment (according to that date), I get the first one. How is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT f.name, cmt.created_at AS CommentDate, cmt.comment AS LastComment
FROM families f
LEFT JOIN comments cmt ON f.id = cmt.commentable_id
WHERE f.id =12212
and cmt.created_at = (
                        SELECT MAX( cmt.created_at ) 
                        FROM families f
                        LEFT JOIN comments cmt ON f.id = cmt.commentable_id
                        WHERE f.id =12212
                      )
```

or

```
SELECT f.name, cmt.created_at AS CommentDate, cmt.comment AS LastComment
FROM families f
LEFT JOIN comments cmt ON f.id = cmt.commentable_id
WHERE f.id =12212
and cmt.created_at = (
                        SELECT MAX( created_at ) 
                        FROM comments
                        WHERE commentable_id =12212
                      )
```

Comment: 2 LEFT JOINs on that table are very expensive, since there are 400,000 rows in that table.

Comment: @NoamB. I added one more solution, with only 1 join.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on Sql-Server: Your query should not be working since there is no grouping.

I think what you need is to take the `TOP(1)` *after ordering* `cmt.created_at DESC`;

```
SELECT TOP (1) f.name, cmt.created_at AS CommentDate, cmt.comment AS LastComment
FROM families f
LEFT JOIN comments cmt ON f.id = cmt.commentable_id
WHERE f.id =12212
ORDER BY cmt.created_at DESC
```

For mysql I think you could use `LIMIT` instead `TOP`:

```
SELECT f.name, cmt.created_at AS CommentDate, cmt.comment AS LastComment
FROM families f
LEFT JOIN comments cmt ON f.id = cmt.commentable_id
WHERE f.id =12212
ORDER BY cmt.created_at DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: He is most likely not on SQL Server, since he has a column and an aggregated function on the `SELECT`, but no `GROUP BY`, this won't parse

Comment: And what if I want the last comment for every family?

Comment: In that case, you may need to find no 1 record after ordering in descending order (equivalent of row_number() in sql-server) and replace comments table with that query and remove the where clause and limit. [Here is an example](http://www.explodybits.com/2011/11/mysql-row-number/) of how to do it on mysql.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what your query is asking for: You are selecting the name, maximum comment date then the first comment that is joined (which, in this case, happens to be the first one). You need to put extra logic in there to get the latest comment.

Different SQL flavours have different ways of doing this, but the following ought to work everywhere:

```
select    f.name,
          cmt.created_at as CommentDate,
          cmt.comment as LastComment
from      families f
left join comments cmt
on        cmt.commentable_id = f.id
left join comments latest_cmt
on        latest_cmt.commentable_id = f.id
and       latest_cmt.created_at > cmt.created_at
where     f.id = 12212
and       latest_cmt.id is null;
```

We assume that the comment table has an `id` field as its primary key.

Comment: 2 LEFT JOINs on that table are very expensive, since there are 400,000 rows in that table.

Comment: Apart from the "ordering and selecting the top one" trick, there's no way you'll get around this: You'll obviously have to join to the comments, but then you need logic to determine the latest. You can either do this by joining again, like I have, or use a subquery; ultimately, the RDBMS will do the same work. If you have appropriate indexes on your `comments` table, the overhead shouldn't be too bad. *If* it turns out to be, then you need to change your schema so that the latest comment is explicitly marked by your application, but this wouldn't come for free, incurring a maintenance burden.